# Paragraphs Align Media Left or Right of Text with CSS

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I am using Paragraphs module to create a cutom paragraph. The custom paragraph will have three fields: Image, Text and Position. Would like to use css to align as follows based on the value of the Position field.

Image Left  | Text Right

Text Left | Image Right

Image Top / Text Below

How do I go about doing this? Do I need any extra configuration for the paragraph? Or is all the magic done in CSS?

Comment: Doing it based on a field is fine, alternatively you can also use the styles feature that we're working on in https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_collection, then you can just define styles and style groups in a yml file with corresponding classes and enable the groups on the paragraph types you want to have this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just CSS. You could use [Classy Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/classy_paragraphs) to append CSS classes to your paragraphs depending on some field values, or you can do this very easily yourself (recommended) by preprocessing the paragraph in your theme's `*.theme` file.

---

Let's assume the position field is a single-value List (Text) field with the following allowed values:

```
image-left|image-left
image-right|image-right
image-top|image-top
```

Then you can easily retrieve that value and append it as CSS class by implementing [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x):

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_paragraph().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];

  // Retrieve certain field's values and add them as CSS classes.
  $classy_fields = [
    'field_image_position',
    'field_background_color',
    'field_social_media_type',
  ];

  foreach ($classy_fields as $classy_field) {

    if ($paragraph->hasField($classy_field)) {

      if (!$paragraph->get($classy_field)->isEmpty()) {

        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $paragraph->get($classy_field)->getString();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

---

Which will result in `image-right` or whatever other class getting appended to this paragraph's attributes and it now can by styled accordingly:

```
<div class="paragraph-MYPARAGRAPH view-mode--default image-right">
```